# how to find user from list inside group entity class

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity class. I am using JPA.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Group implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @Column(nullable = false)
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
   private long id;
   @OneToOne
   private User ownerId;
   @OneToMany
   private List<User> groupMember;

   private String name;

   //settter and getter
}
```

Now i have to find whether User who belongs to any group or not

If user belongs to group then to which group.

Method by which I can achieve it:
To read all group row and find the user from group.groupMember by iteration
but it is not a nice method.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have 2 ways to doing it:

1) Either iterate all groups and find if user belongs to any group or

2) write a sql query which does the same for you.

what ever approach you use, it will be always a "heavy/not preferred" solution, because it need a lot of processing.

Instead what you can do is you can change the domain model. you can put a reference of Group inside the user. So, that when you have user you will already have a group and you dont need to perform above 2 heavy operations.

For doing so you dont have to change your domain model more. you can simply add a Group reference inside your user entity by giving OneToOne relationship and storing the group inside the user and you are done. Now, when you retrieve a user, you will also get a group associated with it.